# Gradle strange behavior while extending sourceSets with Map variable

Tags: java, gradle

We are developing a Java project that is able to instrument (change) class files at build time. We defined a Gradle task that invokes a java based Ant task which takes an inputDir (e.g. build/classes) and an outputDir (e.g. build/classes-instrumented) and possible other parameters. The task gets invoked separately for main and test class files after compilation. Since the "normal" java sourceSet is not a good fit, our first thought was to implement our own sourceSet but couldn't find an easy way. A reasonable alternative, similar to ANTLR etc, seemed to be extra variables. Since I needed several, I went for a Map.

```
sourceSets.all { ext.instrumentation = [:] }

sourceSets.all {
    instrumentation.inputDir = null
    instrumentation.outputDir = null
    instrumentation.classPath = null
}

def postfix = '-instrumented'
```

Below you see how we initialize the variables.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        instrumentation.inputDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
        instrumentation.outputDir = instrumentation.inputDir + postfix
        instrumentation.classPath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.compile
    }

    test {
        instrumentation.inputDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
        instrumentation.outputDir = instrumentation.inputDir + postfix
    }
}
```

However it fails with "Could not find method main() for arguments [build_f2cvmoa3v4hnjefifhpuk6ira$_run_closure5_closure23@12a14b74] on root
project 'Continuations'."

We are using Gradle 2.1

I have the following questions:

1. any idea why the first one fails?
2. Is the extra variable a reasonable solution to approach the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: did you have "apply plugin: 'java'" anywhere in your build.gradle or at global init.d level .gradle file? Why don't you use jacoco.

Comment: Yes, the gradle file contains "apply plugin:'java'", because the java plugin provides the core sourceSet implementation.
JaCoCo is java code coverage. I don't understand why think this is useful? Out byte code modifications have nothing to do with code coverage.

Comment: I found similar issue when we're using Gradle 1.6 and someone jumped from that version to Gradle 2.x. Can you run the same using Gradle version < 2.1 and see what's the latest version where you'll not find this error - cannot find method main()

Answer (score 0):

**solution**: install last version.

I had the same problem, I read gradle documentation of gradle 3, but gradle 2.7 was installed.

- checked gradle version 2.7
- then read gradle 2.7 doc `https://docs.gradle.org/2.7/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N103CD` , but found no info about sourceSet in java plugin for that version
- installed gradle 3 --> **problem solved**